# Is the trajectory of a bubble a good indicator of the direction and velocity of air flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bubbles

I'm wondering if a soap bubble is a good "measurement device" for the flow field of air it is surrounded by. If I could somehow create many bubbles in an array, could I infer the flow field of the air from their position data? If not, what would be the main issues? Would nearby bubbles disrupt each other?

Comment: the wind strength? https://www.videoblocks.com/video/authenticity-little-girl-soap-bubbles-wind-a-little-girl-in-a-playground-is-blowing-into-a-plastic-circle-trying-to-make-soap-bubbles-but-the-wind-is-too-strong-outdoors-shot-cloudy-cold-day-rgon1fipxj19en61u

Comment: You should check out the [Stokes number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_number); it is dimensionless number which quantifies if a particle will follow streamlines of the flow or detach from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bubbles would not give you a good idea of the flow field. Some of the issues are that the bubbles are relatively large in size, can deform, and will coalesce when they approach each other. Because they are large in size, they will not simply measure the velocity field but will also change the velocity field. The fact that they can deform, pop, and coalesce makes their impact on the velocity field even greater. You'll notice that when you blow on a soap bubble, it doesn't alway follow the trajectory you expect.

Your idea to use trackable entities to measure a flow field is essentially Particle Image Velocimetry (PIV). This measurement technique seeds the flow with many small, neutrally buoyant particles and tracks the displacement of each particle, from which velocity is then calculated. In air, I believe that it is common to use an oil atomizer to create very small oil droplets that move with the flow. In fluids like water you can buy special PIV particles.